# Layout percentage vs. padding

Tags: css, layout, percentage

I have an interesting problem that came up more than once. I'll present the last one and uploaded both of them to my server.

I'm taking a tuts+ course about responsive webdesign and as the guy has set 20% for creating 5 grids + 2x5px padding between them, it didn't work to me unless I changed the 20 to 19%.

This is my code:

```
/* WIDTH SETTING */

.nav-hold,
.image-grid,
.container {
    width:95%;
    max-width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

/* IMAGE GRID */
.image-grid,
.form-container {
    overflow: hidden; /* because inside the grid, we'll flow elements */
    padding: 5px;
}

.image-grid-square {
    float: left;
    width: 19%; /* each img container's width (5*)19% */
    overflow: hidden; /* because inside the grid, we'll flow elements */
    padding: 5px;
}

.image-grid-square img {
    width: 100%; /* the img inside the container can be 100% big */
    float: left;
}
```

The only change in his code is the width:20%; (at least what I noticed)

If you guys want to inspect the code deeper, here is my version: http://purpost.me and here is his version: http://purpost.me/tuts

Why his 20% for 5 grids or 25% for 4 grids works perfectly and mine doesn't? :) I'm learning CSS and have a short amount of time to get to know the most of it to use it in a big project. I want to understand the behavior of layouts to be able to build an any type of site. I know frameworks such as Bootstrap, but the command is to use our own codes, so I'm learning as fast as I can. :)

In the course the 300x300 pictures became 188x188, but when I tried it with 20%, mine was 200x200 .. now with 19% its 190x190. I don't understand.

*I understand most of the key factors of responsive web-design unless this grid question. I assume I should read a lot about it and try and try and try and in the end I'll be comfortable using it.*

**I appreciate any help, thanks in advance!**

Comment: It appears to be working correctly to me (both of them) what browser are you using?  -  I'm in Chrome and Firefox FYI

Comment: It's working perfectly because on http://purpost.me I changed the width to 19%, but on the http://purpost.me/tuts the attribute is 20%. I'm using Chrome, but the problem isn't with the browser. :)

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding but unless you're viewing at 480px wide screen size, you'll see the exact same thing on both pages.  At 480 it just makes the 19% show one per line and the 20% is 2 per line.

Comment: You're misunderstanding. :) Try to change the 19% to 20% on Chrome inspector or Firebug! The class is image-grid-square. You'll notice that then on my site the grid become 4, but on the other site with 20% the grid's number is 5. That's the mystery for me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other guy is having reset.css file where he has some css definitions which you are not using. That is why your UI behaves different.

[image]

Comment: It's funny. :) I downloaded the exact reset file that he recommended Eric Meyer’s “Reset CSS” 2.0, but now I deleted it and changed it to that one that he used.. and it's working perfectly! Thank you! :)

Do you recommend using my own reset settings?

Comment: It depends upon your requirement. You can use your own if you think that is more efficient... :)